# PHP preg_replace - include the pattern / full subject in the result

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've a problem that I couldn't solve myself: replace...

```
locale("Sendx", "Send")
locale("System", "System")
```

***should become:***

```
locale("Sendx", "Subsub")
locale("System", "Newsys")
```

I tried a simple replace:

```
$mysearchword = "System"; #changes in a loop
$myreplaceword = "Newsys"; #also changes in the loop
$oneline = str_replace($mysearchword, $myreplaceword, $oneline);
```

but the result looks like

```
locale("Sendx", "53ND")
locale("Newsys", "Newsys") #problem with the doubled word
```

of course the System was replaced both times. So I decided to use **preg_replace**

```
$pattern = '/locale\\(["|\']([^"\']*)["|\'], ["|\']([^"\']*)["|\']\\)/';
$replacement = '${1}, Newsys';
$subject = 'locale("System", "System")';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
```

But now nearly anything is missing, because only the words in the brackets are returned and I have no idea how to include the pattern or return a replaced $subject.
The $pattern changes, so I couldn't write "locale(..." into the $replacement / I somehow must return a replaced pattern...

```
System, Newsys # No idea how to combine $replacement with $pattern...
```

Could you please help me to get the right result?

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid to split a string before doing regex on the last part. Probably makes it a lot easier and results in more readable code :)

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
$input  = 'locale("Sendx", "Send")';
$output = preg_replace('/, "(.*?)"/', ', "Subsub"', $input);
echo $output;
echo "\n";

$input  = 'locale("System", "System")';
$output = preg_replace('/, "(.*?)"/', ', "Newsys"', $input);
echo $output;
```

Output:

```
locale("Sendx", "Subsub")
locale("System", "Newsys")
```

The pattern `/, "(.*?)"/` searches for the word between double quotes `"` after the comma and replaces it with `, "NEW_WORD"`

Using this pattern, you can easily replace them in a loop:

```
$input = array(
  'locale("Sendx", "Send")' => 'Subsub',  
  'locale("System", "System")' => 'Newsys'
);

foreach($input as $string => $replacement) {
    $output = preg_replace('/, "(.*?)"/', ', "' . $replacement . '"', $string);
    echo $output. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: @sln Hey! you are really a human! :) I must admit, I thought that your answer was given by a machine! Sorry.. What do you mean with constants?

Comment: You're connecting a constant input string to a replacement string, but the regex doesn't work on variable data. It works on the constant which is tied to a fixed replacement.

Comment: Yeah but that was the requirement in the question. Otherwise `preg_quote` might being used. Isn't it?

Comment: On the subject string, its really just a FIND: `locale("Sendx", "Send")`, REPLACE:  `locale("Sendx", "Subsub")`. Same for `"System"` => `"Newsys"`, but the find's are part of the regex. The regex can't be fixed to `"(.*?)"`. I mean it could if it were a callback, the match is checked against "Send" or "System" and replaced appropriatly, which is probably the way I would do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't get you. Maybe you could give an example?

Comment: @sln I think you missed that I match against `, "(.*?")` not just `(.*?)`

Comment: His point being (I believe), because it matches `(.*?)` if you ran it against the OPs `locale("Sendx", "Send") locale("System", "System")` you'd end up with both `Send` and `System` being replaced by `Newsys`, you literally have to run this against the exact line you want to do the replacement in for it to work as is. So you may as well just be replacing the entire input with your entire desired output. But hey, apparently it's what the OP wanted.

Comment: @OGHaza Thx for the comment! Now I got it. I also think replacing line by line is what OP wanted.

Comment: I don't think he mentioned that. The OP says he's got text he wants to turn into other text. 2 lines in total. And, yes that was my point.

Comment: @sln Have you tried to compare the performance of iterating trough lines using my attempt and replacing the all at once as you've  suggested? I'm just asking. Would be nice to see how large the input needs to be to make yours more performant. I guess there is some point, but not sure.. However, I still think your attempt is much to complicated and unmaintenable (after written).. Also there is `sed` which could be called in that situation, which looks more performant even than the craziest PCRE (imo)

Comment: hek, to use your approach iterating through lines you'd first have to go through the code yourself, find each line that needs a replacement, build a dictionary of each line to replace and the appropriate replacement string. Then you'd need to iterate through the lines, check if the line exists in your dictionary, then do the replacement.... am I wrong?

Comment: @hek2mgl - If the file is really big, and has a lot of independent possible replacements, yes, it could be faster. Especially if its a preformed (reliable) constant regex. For example `, "\s*([^"]*?)\s*"`, to get the key, then a hash table like lookup for the replacement.

Comment: @OGHaza I could extends the pattern to `/locale\("(.*?)", "(.*?)"\)/`... and the replacement to `locale("$1", "REPLACEMENT")`

Answer (score 2):

It could be just need to replace second variable.
Do a new preg_replace each time you want to replace something.
This regex uses a branch reset to resolve quotes.

```
 # FIND: 
 # $pattern =
 # '/(?s)(?|(locale\s*\(\s*"[^"\\\]*(?:\\\.[^"\\\]*)*"\s*,\s*"\s*)'
 # . $whatyouwanttofind .
 # '(\s*"\s*\))|(locale\s*\(\s*\'[^\'\\\]*(?:\\\.[^\'\\\]*)*\'\s*,\s*\'\s*)'
 # . $whatyouwanttofind .
 # '(\s*\'\s*\)))/';
 # 
 # REPLACE:  ${1}$whatyouwanttoreplace${2}

 (?s)
 (?|
      (                             # (1 start)
           locale
           \s* 
           \(
           \s* 
           " [^"\\]* (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )* " 
           \s* , \s* 
           " 
           \s* 
      )                             # (1 end)
      what you want to find
      (                             # (2 start)
           \s* 
           " 
           \s* 
           \)
      )                             # (2 end)
   |  
      (                             # (1 start)
           locale
           \s* 
           \(
           \s* 
           ' [^'\\]* (?: \\ . [^'\\]* )* ' 
           \s* , \s* 
           ' 
           \s* 
      )                             # (1 end)
      what you want to find
      (                             # (2 start)
           \s* 
           ' 
           \s* 
           \)
      )                             # (2 end)
 )
```

Comment: What is this? Why do you complicate a simple problem?

Comment: Rock-solid solution, dare I say unbreakable..?

Comment: @OGHaza - Thanks! It is kind of unweildly. A lot could be trimmed if more were known about the real form.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how well formed this input is, but something along the lines of this will work for your example:

```
(locale\("[^"]*",\s*")System("\))
```

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?383ba)

In PHP:

```
$find = 'System';
$replace = 'Newsys';

$pattern = '/(locale\("[^"]*",\s*")'.$find.'("\))/';
$replacement = '$1'.$replace.'$2';
$subject = 'locale("System", "System")';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject); 
//Outputs: locale("System", "Newsys")
```

Answer (score 0):

How complex does the replacement need to be?  This will work in that specific example:

```
$str = '
locale("Sendx", "Send")
locale("System", "System")';

$str =
str_replace('"System", "System"', '"System", "Newsys"',
str_replace('"Send"', '"Subsub"', $str));

echo "<pre>$str</pre>";
```